# Pagination in scrollview

Tags: iphone

_

```
viewdidload
{
    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subview.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
        [subview release];
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * colors.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = colors.count;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    if (!pageControlBeingUsed) {
        // Switch the indicator when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible
        CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
        self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
    }
}
```

i am using this code for displaying pagination in scrollview with different colors,for identification,i just want to replace it with images instead of colors.i am using this code

```
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"h1@2x"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"h2@2x"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"h2.1@2x"], nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

        UIImageView*subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        UIImage *imggg = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
        [subview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:imggg]];

        [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
        [subview release];
    }
```

But i get only two view, and the image is not size to fit it is delocated.How to set images with the above code.Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer by reducing the size of the images in the array to exactly the size of the scrollview.  My scrollview size is 320,424, and I slice the size of the images to 320,424.  It works perfectly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *subview = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
[subview setBackgroundColor:[colors objectAtIndex:i]];

[[self scrollView] addSubview:subview];
```

this looks like what your code is trying to do...

If you want images on each page though:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nameOfImageFile"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img] autorelease];

[[self scrollView] addSubview:imageView];
```

to have multiple images for each page, just use an array of UIImages for the page.

```
NSArray *imageNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"image1Name", @"image2name", @"image3Name", nil];

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:pageNumber]];
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img] autorelease];

[[self scrollView] addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: but in the above code i get only @"nameOfImageFile" one image,but i have multiple image to lode on each page.

Comment: see addition for an implementation with multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
}

@end

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chiranjeevi.jpeg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"AR.jpeg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"sachin.jpeg"], nil];
     scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*colors.count,scrollView.frame.size.height);
     for (int i = 0; i <[colors count]; i++) 
    {
        UIImage *imggg = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x =scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = scrollView.frame.size;      

        UIImageView *subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subview.image=imggg;

        [scrollView addSubview:subview];

    }

}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```